# Updating a column with the column beside it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to update the column with a column beside it after removing the gaps in date. For Example if first effective period is (1/4/2014-30/4/2014) and second effective period is (15/5/2014 - 31/5/2014), there is a gap of 15 days. Now I need to Update the first effective to i.e 30/4/2014 to 1 date before the the next effective from i.e. 1 day - 15/5/2014 = 14/5/2014. 
Table[image]

Expected update[image]

I tried getting the result by this code i.e.

```
    Update ItemHospitalMapping
    Set EffectiveTo = (select DATEADD(dd,-1,A.EffectiveFrom) 
from ItemHospitalMapping as a join ItemHospitalMapping as B 
on a.NameOfHospital=B.NameOfHospital 
and a.NameOfItem=B.NameOfItem 
Where a.EffectiveTo >B.EffectiveTo)
    where NameOfHospital=any(select  a.NameOfHospital 
                             from ItemHospitalMapping as a join ItemHospitalMapping as B 
                             on a.NameOfHospital=B.NameOfHospital and a.NameOfItem=B.NameOfItem 
                             Where a.EffectiveTo >B.EffectiveTo) and
          EffectiveTo=any(select B.EffectiveTo 
                         from ItemHospitalMapping as a join ItemHospitalMapping as B 
                         on a.NameOfHospital=B.NameOfHospital and a.NameOfItem=B.NameOfItem 
                         Where a.EffectiveTo >B.EffectiveTo)
```

But haven't been successful in returning a single row for the update. Error that I am getting is  Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: due to subquery in any

Comment: your table looks so messed up. a1000 diol a2 row has toDate < fromDate. How do you decide 29th or 30th is the To date for a particular row ?

Comment: The table above has the result now we see a gap in the dates i.e for A1000|Diol|a1|Hasmath Hospital|100.00|50.00|2014-04-13|2014-04-29 there are two records with different effectiveFrom and different EffectiveTo. There is a gap between the first effectiveTo and the second effectiveFrom. i.e. between 2014-04-29 and 2014-04-31 so I need to remove that 1 day gap and update the previous date that is 2014-04-29 to 2014-04-30

Comment: I have come close By using this code
'Update a
Set a.EffectiveTo = DATEADD(dd,-1,a.EffectiveFrom) 
from ItemHospitalMapping as a join ItemHospitalMapping as B 
on a.NameOfHospital=B.NameOfHospital and a.NameOfItem=B.NameOfItem 
Where a.EffectiveTo >B.EffectiveTo'
but the second effective period' effectiveTo is getting updated not the First EffectiveTo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for contributing your valuable time. I have been trying to work on the solution for a long time now and happened to solve the problem with the below code.

```
 Update B
    Set B.EffectiveTo = DATEADD(dd,-1,a.EffectiveFrom) 
    from ItemHospitalMapping as a join ItemHospitalMapping as B 
    on a.NameOfHospital=B.NameOfHospital and a.NameOfItem=B.NameOfItem 
    Where a.EffectiveTo >B.EffectiveTo
```